# While Loop Skipping Over getchar and Comparison Between Pointer and Integer

Tags: c

So i'm new to c and I have 2 problems with this code:

```
#import <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char answer;
    int playerX = 0;
    int playerY = 0;
    int done = 0;
    char direction[] = "none";

    while (done == 0){
        printf("Direction:\n");
        a = getchar();

        if (answer == "u"){
            playerY += 1;
        } else{

        }
        printf("Your current position is: %d,%d\n", playerX, playerY);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

1. On line 14 it says "warning: comparison between pointer and integer"
2. With only 1 input (being u) and nothing else I see this:

Direction:
u
Your current position is: 0,0
Direction:
Your current position is: 0,0
Direction:

Comment: `"u"` is a string literal. `'u'` is a character constant.

Comment: You have also entered a newline.

Comment: `a = getchar()`.  Perhaps you meant: `answer = getchar()` ?

Comment: `char answer;` ==> `int answer;` because that is the return type from `getchar`. Beginners often make the incorrect assumption that when working with characters, a `char` type is needed. Note that `'u'` is of type `int` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am assuming you have "#include" instead of "import" in line 1, and "answer" instead of "a" in line 12.

To answer the actual question you have, in C char and string are different. You have a char type variable answer, that you are comparing with the string "u". As a result, the compiler is creating a constant string "u" and comparing the pointer to that string with the char type variable answer. Your check should instead have

```
if(answer == 'u') {
```